# Mi5 'It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked) Application will be closed' issue

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I tried to run a simple camera OpenCV on mi 5. I installed the OpenCV_2.4.3_Manager_2.0_armeabi.apk but my mobile screen displayed 'It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked). Application will be closed' at the time of opening the app. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 has introduced a new permission model. Application has to request the user for granting some permissions manually, declaration in Manifest is not enough.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Going to: Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions and enabling the Camera permission

should also work, but might not be too elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Check in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"/>
```

or, check in your device

> Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions and enabling the Camera permission

or,

> kill any other apps that are using the camera.

If those doesn't work! You device doesn't support openCV, not all devices support it!

Comment: i had already added the permissions and it was working fine for some mobile devices and tested on version 5.1 also it was working fine but it is not working on android version 6.0 on mi devices.